# How to order by specific format from a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bash

i have a column that contains data like this:

```
{Population: 1331415}
{Population: 44234}
{Population: 214124212}
{Population: 222222}
```

i need to order the database by the number after {Population: ,and by another column called Name(it contains names of cities)

Comment: First of all, why are you storing data like that. It can be stored in two different columns or if `Population` is the only value then it can be made as a column

Comment: Is this a plain file, and are you allowed to use external shell utilities or only native sql queries?

Comment: Just to understand which language to use: what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use the length and the value:

```
order by length(col) desc, col desc
```

Another is to extract the numeric value and convert it to a number:

```
order by substring_index(col, ': ', -1) + 0 desc
```

Comment: when i try to use a function like that it says that the function is not installed. I use mysql from a terminal

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - nice to add 0 to eliminate the **}** at the end of line - vote up

Comment: @BerndBuffen - I believe that it is to `cast` the data implicitly to `int` to avoid string ordering

Comment: @RazvanBuzatu . . . `length()` and `substring_index()` are both native functions to MySQL.  What database are you really using?

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sort`, with `-n` for numeric sort  and `-k` flag for sorting based on the `2nd` field.

```
sort -n -k2 file
{Population: 44234}
{Population: 222222}
{Population: 1331415}
{Population: 214124212}
```

Comment: you can add `sort -V inputfile` as well if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
            ORDER BY 
            CONVERT( (REPLACE (substring_index(ColumnName, ': ',-1),'}','')), 
            UNSIGNED  INTEGER ) DESC
```

Sample :

```
        SELECT * ,
        CONVERT((REPLACE(substring_index(A, ': ',-1),'}','')),UNSIGNED  INTEGER )'ORDER'
        FROM (
            SELECT '{Population: 1331415}' AS A UNION
            SELECT '{Population: 44234}' UNION
            SELECT '{Population: 214124212}' UNION
            SELECT '{Population: 222222}'
            )B 
        ORDER BY 
        CONVERT( (REPLACE (substring_index(A, ': ',-1),'}','')), UNSIGNED  INTEGER )
        DESC
```

> Output :

[image]