# sort numerically according to substring extracted from varchar field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which contains 2 columns { Names of cities and Info}

```
Name    Info
Qandahar    {"Population": 237500}
Kabul    {"Population": 1780000}
Herat    {"Population": 186800}
Mazar-e-Sharif    {"Population": 127800}
Amsterdam    {"Population": 731200}
Rotterdam    {"Population": 593321}
```

and so on. I tried to sort it by Population but this does not work

```
SELECT Name,Info ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Info, 16, LENGTH(Info)-16) AS INT) FROM city
```

but it outputs nothing. I get ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) FROM city' at line 1.

Comment: try to use `order by` clause after `FROM city`

Comment: try this SELECT Name, CAST(SUBSTRING(Info, 16, LENGTH(Info)-16) AS INT) as info_cast FROM city order by info_cast

Comment: i get invalid syntax for this too.

Comment: If you test the request without order by? You get an error?

Comment: @adikinzor Please [edit] you question to include the error message.

Comment: try this `SELECT Name, CAST(SUBSTRING(Info, 16, LENGTH(Info)-16)) as info_cast FROM city order by info_cast`

Comment: @nimourpristou no i dont

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order by specific format from a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182865/how-to-order-by-specific-format-from-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast as `INT`

> These are the following data type you can cast
>
> - `BINARY[(N)]`
> - `CHAR[(N)]`
> - `DATE`
> - `DATETIME`
> - `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`
> - `SIGNED [INTEGER]`
> - `TIME`
> - `UNSIGNED [INTEGER]`

You need to use this:

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Info,
  CAST(SUBSTRING(Info, 16, LENGTH(Info)-16) AS UNSIGNED) as info_cast 
FROM city 
order by info_cast
```

Answer is taken from: [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted the symbols from the left, but you need to delete a } symbol from the right before casting. Like this:

CAST(TRIM(TRAILING '}' FROM SUBSTRING(Info,16,LENGTH(Info)-16)) AS INT)

By the way, why do you use such a table structure? Wouldn't it be better to have an integer column to keep integers?

CREATE TABLE Info (
  NAME VARCHAR(20),
  POPULATION INT)